# bladeでヘッダーを使い回したい

Tags: php, laravel

bladeで各ページ共通のヘッダー(あるいはフッター)を作りたいのですが、linkタグも含めて便利に使い回せるようにできますでしょうか。
例えばこんな感じのヘッダーです。

```
<link href='/css/header.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<div>abc</div>
```

div部分だけならbodyタグ内だけなので簡単だと思うのですが、linkタグ部分はheadタグ内に配置したいです。
その場合に@ディレクティブ(@sectionなど)をどのように作成すれば良いでしょうか。
(一応linkタグでもbody内に置けますが今回それは考えません)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もっともシンプルに行うなら継承（extend）を利用してください。

まずはベースとなるcommonのレイアウトを作ります。
もっともシンプルなbody>header,content,footer というレイアウトだとすると

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/layouts/common.blade.php -->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
        <link href='/css/header.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">abc</div>
        <div class="content">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        <div id="footer">abc</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

それらを利用したいviewで継承（extend）を利用します。

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/index.blade.php -->

@extends('layouts.common')

@section('title', 'index Page')

@section('content')
    <p>This is index body content.</p>
@endsection
```

例えばindex2という同じようなページを利用する場合です。

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/index2.blade.php -->

@extends('layouts.common')

@section('title', 'index2 Page')

@section('content')
    <p>This is index2 body content.</p>
@endsection
```

参考
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade
https://qiita.com/makies/items/2ab24188e7f8482bfddc